# Why can't I refer to a nested object in React Native in my mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, react-native, api, reference

I got a simple question about object reference which seems pretty strait forward to me (I'm new to programming). When I get an item from my mongDB through this function:

```
const workAPI = async () => {
const response = await trackerAPI.get("/workouts");
setResults(response);
console.log(results);
```

};

I get my list of workouts, which are objects. One workout object looks like this:

```
Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "6183a09df3ba372d5d182ee3",
  "exercises": Array [
    Object {
      "_id": "6183a09df3ba372d5d182ee4",
      "exerciseProps": Object {
        "reps": 4,
        "sets": 3,
        "time": 20,
      },
      "exerciseTitle": "running",
    },
  ],
  "title": "Jdbsv",
  "userId": "615e06f36ce5e5f1a69c675e",
```

So everything is fine, I have my whole list of workouts logged, but why can't I log a property from a workout through the following function:

```
const workAPI = async () => {
const response = await trackerAPI.get("/workouts");
setResults(response);
console.log(results._id);
```

};

The _id is a property every workout has, I also tried to fill in an actual _id through a string (that's what I want to use it for), but neither did that work. Is it only possible to refer to the _id through mapping?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems your api returns an array of workout. At first you should select an element from the array, say first element, and then log the _id property of that element.

```
console.log(results[0]._id)
```

Not to mention that the zero here is called the index of that element in the array and the element indexes start from 0.

Comment: Well, it still wouldn't fix, but I found my way around this problem by either using JSON.stringify, or making a path in my back end API directly to that _id, anyway thanks a lot for the help!